# Gitlab-ci for specific directories in same repository

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

We are merging over to Git in our company. We have this specific case where our master-branch is our development branch and every release-version is a branched version of the master-branch. These release-versions are branched into tailored customer-versions. So we are using a monolothic repository.

We have a couple of projects in each branch. Every project needs its own ci. The first problem we met, was the fact that the gitlab-runner automatically clones the entire branch. This practically meant that loads of unnecessary files were copied into projects that did not even use the files. This problem was partly dealt with by using `GIT_STRATEGY: none` in the `.gitlab-ci.yml`, disabling the automatic cloning and forcing us to manually pull the files we needed in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` script section.

This was done using git's sparse-checkout. Locally everything worked fine, but when we tried it using gitlab-ci the pull request that is defined in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` script section for some reason got stuck. We went over to the server and tried running the same 'git pull origin master'-command that got the gitlab-runner stuck and noticed a problem. The pull request required authentication.

- Question 1: How can we deal with this authentication required for the pull only using `.gitlab-ci.yml` or maybe gitlab-runner's configs? We know there is this authentication method for the clone operation, but cloning is not really an option for us as far as we know (Since it always copies everything from the branch):
  `http://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@repository.git`
- Question 2: We noticed git has to be 'init:ed' when we run the job scripts for new projects. That's is all fine and dandy since running git init on an already existing local repo only reinitalizes it (shouldn't be a problem). But we also have to add our remote (`git remote add origin %repositoryURL%`). This causes problems, since running the same `git remote add origin` command written in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` causes fatal error during the ci-run, resulting in a failed build. This only happens if the remote already is added from before, so manually removing the config file could be a solution? Removing a remote that doesn't exist also causes fatal error, so remove -> add remote every time the job runs won't suffice.

Thanks for the patience. We know this is not the optimal solution and multi-repo would be far easier, but we really want to keep our current working tree structure.

Comment: Could you clone the entire repository and trigger job only on [changes](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/#onlychangesexceptchanges) in specific directory ?

Comment: Can you post some examples of your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file and the error messages that you get? GitLab has experimental features for partial clones, here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/git/partial_clone.html

Comment: For the second part of your question, you can always have script lines in your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file that ORs with something that succeeds, e.g. `git remote add origin || true`, and then your GitLab job should continue even if the first part of the command fails.